# Android Calling API and parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Trying to make an API call to the url below and parse the returning JSON, when the "refresh" button is called.

I can link to a button and get text (Hello world) to the screen, but can't seem to link the button click to the API request. Error message says I cannot reference non-static method "execute" from a static context

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void retrieveInformation(View view){
    RetrieveFeedTask.execute();
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
    textview.setText("Hello world");
}

class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String jsonString = "";

    private Exception exception;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

        // Do some validation here

        try {
            URL url = new URL("www.liftin.co.uk/api/v1/journeys");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        Log.i("INFO", response);
        jsonString = response;
        try {
            getInformationFromJson(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getInformationFromJson(String jsonString)
        throws JSONException {
        final String DRIVER = "driver";
        final String START = "start";
        final String DESTINATION = "destination";
        final String TIME = "pick_up_time";
        final String PASSENGERS = "passengers";
        final String SEATS = "seats_available";

        JSONObject journeyJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        String time = journeyJson.getString(TIME);
        String seats = journeyJson.getString(SEATS);

        String results = seats + "-----" + time;
        return results;
    }


}
```

}

Main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.liftin.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/queryButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:onClick="retrieveInformation"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/responseView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You wrote you have linked but I cannot see any calls of `setOnClickListener` and `retrieveInformation`.

Comment: it is triggered by button click in main_activity.xml

Comment: @Joshua.. He did it in `XML` file inside `button` widget. like `android:onClick="retrieveInformation"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create asynchronous call for your AsyncTask like this :

```
public void retrieveInformation(View view){
    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();    //asynchronous call
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
    textview.setText("Hello world");
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to set data to textview after parsing data. You have to make little bit changes in your activity as follows.

1. You should initialize your `textview` in onCreate() and make it global variable for your activity, so that you can access it in full activity.
2. then in your `onPostExecute()` do this :

   `textview.setText(getInformationFromJson(response));`

Hope it will Help :)

Comment: put bracks "()" after class name. Like this `RetrieveFeedTask()`

Comment: Cheers - got it working - information is displayed to the logs but can't get to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a object of AsyncTask (RetrieveFeedTask) before calling it. For example

```
   public void retrieveInformation(View view){
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        textview.setText("Hello world");
        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to pass something for `Void`.

```
public void retrieveInformation(View view){
    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(null);
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
    textview.setText("Hello world");
}
```